# js file reload after ajax response success

Tags: javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"ajax/ajax_show_sears_update.php",
    data:dataString,
    success:function(response){ 
       //alert(response);
       $("#search_data_show").html(response);
       // give me suggesion, here js file reload
    }
});
```

Html code

```
<script src="js/abc.js"></script>
```

Comment: if you want to reload full page then use location.reload(true) ; if you want only js file  as far as i know it's know possible.

Comment: You cannot refresh only js content in a page

Comment: i dont need to reload full page,  i want refresh js file only

Answer (score 0):

You want to reload the page after the ajax response?

try this:

```
location.reload():
```

Comment: but i want refresh only js file not full page

Comment: what do you mean by refresh js file ?

Comment: please be specific with your question and format your codes properly.

Comment: location.reload() will load page from cache. use location.reload(true) it will load fresh page

Comment: unfortunately, you cannot refresh a js file, but you can put your javascript logic inside the success function..

Comment: but no need to reload page, because i show data in search_data_show div with the help of ajax . i want refresh js file in ajax

Comment: in js file write code of reponsive page, so when show more data footer are not adjust so i like to refresh js file

Comment: he asks to reload the page, so i answered that way, he didnt give specifics.

Comment: so guys are you understand my question...?